# Do "blocking" php scripts consume system resources

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand better what "blocking" php is.

Say I have a server with 1 CPU thread, and I use PHP to connect to a remote database.

Is the CPU thread "blocked" while waiting for the remote DB to respond? Could another PHP process start up and run while the first php process is waiting for the remote DB's response?

Comment: First of all, who told you about "blocking"? Why do you bring this up? On modern servers CPU's are never "blocked".

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Well I remember the big thing with Nginx vs Apahce was that Nginx used a "non-blocking" architecture. Meaning it could serve ~unlimited connections until system resources ran out. Apache could only serve 1 connection per thread. Now I'm seeing the same "nonblocking" words thrown around with say PHP vs Node.js and I'm trying to understand if it is similar to the Nginx Apache situation, or something different.

Comment: "Blocking" basically means that one "thing" waits, for another "thing" to complete, before it executes. Within PHP there are things that block, but also things that are non-blocking. So it depends on exactly what you're doing with PHP. Connecting to a DB is normally always "blocking" within PHP, because PHP needs the data from the database before it can continue. This blockage within PHP has nothing to do with your single CPU. It will happily do something else while PHP waits. I don't believe your server has only one "tread". You probably have a shared server with little CPU resources.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you that's what I was trying to figure out. I'm using an EC2 instance on AWS, and thus far system performance isn't a problem. I'm just not that much of a back end guy, so I wanted to make sure the framework would be scalable for the future.